# Read list of int from Console

Tags: f#

Here is what I want:

```
let rec getList (cnt:int, acc: int list): int list =
    if cnt = 0 then
        acc
    else
        let n = Console.ReadLine() |> int
        getList (cnt-1) n::acc
```

And call it like this:

```
getList 10 []
```

To read 10 integers from standard input and return list of 10 integers.
But I get the error:

> getList (cnt-1) n::acc   --------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> /Users/demas/temporary/stdin(890,9): error FS0003: This value is not a
>   function and cannot be applied

Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function takes a single tuple as arg and you're calling it with two arguments. It should be `getList (cnt-1, n::acc)`.

Comment: Thanks, I fix a function declaration to get int and list of int.